# Weka, merging arff files

Tags: weka, arff

I have several .arff files that were generated for the same datasets. Each contains a different set of features. Is there a way to merge these files?
Same instances, but different attributes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the weka.core.Instances method to merge two datasets with 
the same number of instances: 
  java weka.core.Instances 1.arff 2.arff > 1_2.arff 
  java weka.core.Instances 1_2.arff 3.arff > 1_2_3.arff